# FTP connection working on FileZilla and command line but not python ftplib

Tags: python, ftplib, vsftpd

I have an ftp server deployed on aws. I can connect to it from FileZilla as well as from the command line. However, the python script I have gives me:

> OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

I know that my script works since I can connect to other servers.

```
def test_connection():
   server = ftplib.FTP()
   server.connect('xx.xxx.xxx.xx')
   server.login('xxxx', 'xxx')
   print(server.dir())
   server.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   test_connection()
```

Any clues what this could be ?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to restructure your code so that credentials are initialized in the `FTP` constructor call.

```
import ftplib
server= ftplib.FTP('server.address.com','USERNAME','PASSWORD')
print(server.dir())
session.quit()
```

Use `ftplib.FTP_TLS` instead if you FTP host requires TLS.

Answer (score 0):

What worked in the end:

I changed the vsftpd config:

listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO

Not exactly sure though what the problem is

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Im having the same issue. Where is that config, in ftplib? What is it?